# Using HttpPostRequestDecoder with Netty 3.x

Tags: post, netty

I'm attempting to use HttpPostRequestDecoder from Netty Extension 1.1.9 with Netty 3.3.1.  I get class cast issues, however, when trying to get from the built-in Netty HttpRequest to what is used in the org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http2 package.

What is the correct way to go about this?

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpRequest request;
HttpPostRequestDecoder decoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder((org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest) request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used the netty extensions but from a quick look at the source it looks like you need to be sure to only use the http codec stuff which is shipped with it. From your description it seems like you try to mix the http codec stuff that comes with netty and the one that comes with netty extension.

Comment: Yes, this was the case..  I was hoping for interoperability between the two.. didn't go as planned so I did a quick and dirty converter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the HttpPostRequestDecoder from the master branch?

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http

It seems to be working for me.  See https://github.com/mashupbots/socko/tree/master/socko-webserver/src/main/java/org/mashupbots/socko/postdecoder

You just have to get all the relevant files into your source directory and change the namespace.

Comment: I haven't made the plunge to the bleeding edge branch yet, still on 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a small converter between the http.DefaultHttpRequest and http2.DefaultHttpRequest implementations:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttpRequest convertedRequest = new org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0, org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http2.HttpMethod.POST, request.getUri());
convertedRequest.setContent(request.getContent());
convertedRequest.setChunked(request.isChunked());
// convert the headers
for (Entry<String, String> entry : request.getHeaders()) {
    convertedRequest.setHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```